# C# XML serialization of generic property

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have following classes:

```
public class Response<T>
{ 
  public string Status { get; set; }
  public T GenericType { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
  public string Number { get; set; }
}
public class Customer
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and would like to get for:

```
var r = new Response<Order>();
r.GenericType = new Order { Number = "1" };
```

following xml after serialization:

```
<Response><Order><Number>1</Number></Order></Response>
```

and for:

```
var r = new Response<Customer>();
r.GenericType = new Customer { Name = "Kowalski" };
```

following xml after serialization:

```
<Response><Customer><Name>Kowalski</Name></Customer></Response>
```

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot.

Marek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) to override how the `XmlSerializer` works.**

That way, you can get the output you're looking for.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your answer. Please see my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pieter for your answer.

Yes, I implemented the `IXmlSerializable` interface and `WriteXml` method of my `Reponse` object looks following:

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteRaw(string.Format("<Status>{0}</Status>", Status));
    var xml = GenericType.Serialize();
    writer.WriteRaw(xml);
}
```

The `Serialize()` extension is a generic method, which serializes any object.

Thanks,

Marek